# Do the books "Fantastic Beasts:Illustrated" and "HP:Page to Screen - Creatures Vault" have the same content?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

I have recently purchased the Illustrated "Fantastic Beasts" book (yet to be delivered). I am planning to buy the "Harry Potter:Page to Screen > Creature Vault" book as well (the purple one)

[image]

Do these two books have the same content ? From what I am assuming, Creature Vault may be aimed at the creatures they show in the movies and should revolve around the process of movie making (I have the artifact vault and am assuming basing on that book) .. "Creature Vault" costs a bomb and I don't want to purchase it if the content is similar to the fantastic beasts illustrated version.

**Please let me know if the two books are different or little intertwined ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an almost complete flip through of both books available on Youtube;

and

As you can see, there's certainly overlap in the *content* (they are, after all referencing much the same material) but the illustrations appear to be different.

[image]

vs.

[image]

Comment: For the record, ASMR flipthroughs are weird and slightly creepy.

Comment: wow ! i didn't know these videos of the books existed, ill skim the video ! (and yes, they are a bit creepy :D)

Comment: thank you for this, i  saw a bit of the video and went ahead and purchased the creature vault .. Its a fantastic book, has additional creatures ( i mean from the movie perspective even the owls were included) - has the whole thing from a movie and technical and creative department perspective !

Comment: @Anu7 - Nice! Now I expect you to **read it obsessively and use it as the basis for lots of questions and answers**

Comment: yes ! all i can read up will keep buying and reading :D